# SKEmitterNode not displaying properly

Tags: sprite-kit

So I have created an SKEmitterNode with the "fire" default template. Okay, great, it looks good on a black background, but with the blue sky background I'm using, the particles are white. How do I fix this and get that red/yellow color with the blue background?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out the blend mode for your emmiter (it can be changed in the particle editor). Also try changing the background color in the particle editor to get the desired effect/color.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I have tried every single blend mode and it still looks white.

Comment: I would say if you have access to any photo editing software such as photoshop or gimp, try it there to see what works best for blending modes. I wouldn't be able to help much if I don't have the images to see what is really happening.